# Replace usage of a class in a specific project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper

I'm using VS2010 with Resharper 5.1.

I have two projects, a library project (Lib) and an application project (App), App references Lib.

Lib contains a class X which is used in both App and Lib. In App i now want to replace all usages of X with class Y. In my case Y is unrelated to X, but it could inherit from X if it makes refactoring easier.

My current plan to use the "Find usages" feature, group by project and change the usages one by one. Is there an easier/automated way to do this?

Comment: what about quick replace in current project - replace class name X with Y?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Structural Search and Replace](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/navigation_search.html#Structural_Search_and_Replace) is your friend here. You get to it through `ReSharper | Find | Search with Pattern...`.

- Define a placeholder of type `X`, name it `TX`.
- Make your Find pattern `$TX$`
- Specify to "Look in" "Project"
- As a check, carry out the search - you should see all the usages of `X`
- Click the Replace toggle button
- Make the Replace pattern the fully-qualified name of `Y`
- Click Replace

ReSharper will show you all the mentions of `X` it wants to replace - ensure the checkbox at the top of the tree is checked, then click Replace.

*edit*

It is indeed by using a *type* placeholder in our Find pattern that ensure that only references to the *type* `X`, rather than anything else named `X`, are renamed.

If you would prefer to end up with

```
using A.B.C;

/* later */
Y obObject = ...
```

rather than

```
A.B.C.Y myObject
```

I *think* you can achieve this through:

1. In `ReSharper | Options`, `Tools | Code Cleanup`, define a new profile which has just "Optimize 'using' directives" checked
2. In `ReSharper | Options`, `Languages | C# | Namespace Imports` add `A.B.C` to "Namespaces that should always be imported`
3. Run `ReSharper | Tools | Cleanup Code` using the profile you just defined
4. Tidy up by removing `A.B.C` from the namespaces list you added it to

although this will also clean up all other `using`s, which might make the version control diff a bit larger than you want.

Comment: I assume the find pattern ensures that only references to the class `X` are replaced, and not occurences of `X` in comments or as property names? Also, as a follow up, what would be the easiest way to replace the fully-qualified names and add the correct `using` statements to the relevant files?